# Find the set of integer solutions to the following equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

$$24x^{5} - y^{2} + 5 = 0$$

Hint: consider the equation mod 8

---

I've been stuck on this question all day, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is it possible tohave an integer $y$ and $y^2 \equiv 5 \pmod 8 \; \; ? \; \;$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Since you said `I've been stuck all day`, it would be better to include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly.  In the future please add those in the body of the question (and not in comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod $8$, it’s $y^2\equiv5.$

Is $y^2\equiv5$ for $y\equiv0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, $ or $7$?